# ‘GetGrade’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I get this problem:
main.cpp:13:20: error: ‘GetGrade’ was not declared in this scope
  GetGrade(examGrade);

My code:

main.cpp

```
#include "examGrade.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Qt Application
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFont font("DejaVu Sans", 18);

    ExamGradeInput* examGrade = new ExamGradeInput();
    examGrade->setFont(font);

    GetGrade(examGrade);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("&Exam grade: ");
    label->setFont(font);
    label->setBuddy(examGrade);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(examGrade);

    //Create and display window 

    QWidget* window = new QWidget();
    window->setWindowTitle("Exam grade Window");
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

examGrade.cpp

```
#include "examGrade.hpp"

ExamGradeInput::ExamGradeInput(QWidget* parent): QSpinBox(parent)
{
    this->setRange(0, 100);
}

int GetGrade(ExamGradeInput* examGrade){

    int grade = (examGrade->text()).toInt();
    return grade;
}
```

examGrade.hpp

```
 #pragma once
 #include <QtWidgets>

 //exaGradeInput inherits from public QSpin Box
 class ExamGradeInput: public QSpinBox
 {
     public: 
        ExamGradeInput(QWidget* parent = 0);
        int GetGrade(ExamGradeInput* examGrade);
 };
```

not entirely sure were I have gone wrong, new to C++ and Qt, been doing it for around a week.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove all the code that isn't pertinent to the problem. That's at least 99% of the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
#include "examGrade.hpp"

ExamGradeInput::ExamGradeInput(QWidget* parent): QSpinBox(parent)
{
    this->setRange(0, 100);
}

int GetGrade(ExamGradeInput* examGrade){

    int grade = (examGrade->text()).toInt();
    return grade;
}
```

Should be:

```
#include "examGrade.hpp"

ExamGradeInput::ExamGradeInput(QWidget* parent): QSpinBox(parent)
{
    this->setRange(0, 100);
}

int ExamGradeInput::GetGrade(ExamGradeInput* examGrade){

    int grade = (examGrade->text()).toInt();
    return grade;
}
```

GetGrade is a function declared inside of your class ExamGradeInput, I would recommend reading up on class member function definitions:

A quick google search brings up:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_class_member_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other comments, you really don't have to hold so many things by pointers. Prefer holding objects by value rather than by pointer. I also question the interface for `getGrade`: it's a method that acts on an object, the object doesn't have to be explicitly passed to it. You also don't have to set font explicitly on everything: the parent font will be inherited by the children, with exception of `QLabel`. Here's a complete example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class ExamGradeInput: public QSpinBox
{
    public:
       ExamGradeInput(QWidget* parent = 0) {}
       int getGrade() const { return value(); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;
    QHBoxLayout layout(&window);
    window.setFont({"DejaVu Sans", 18});

    ExamGradeInput examGrade;
    examGrade.getGrade();
    QLabel label("&Exam grade: ");
    label.setBuddy(&examGrade);
    label.setFont(window.font());

    layout.addWidget(&label);
    layout.addWidget(&examGrade);

    window.setWindowTitle("Exam grade Window");
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```